# How to show Properties Dialog like in Explorer? (in WPF)

Tags: wpf, properties, dialog, explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I display a file’s Properties dialog from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936682/how-do-i-display-a-files-properties-dialog-from-c)

Hello. Is there a way to show the exact (ie. not simulated) Properties dialog in WPF? The one in Explorer's context menu? Thanks

Comment: Why does it have to be the exact same dialog?
And do you want to show properties of a file, or just some other object, but in a window that looks exactly the same as Properties?

Comment: Yes, of a file. Hopefully like Properties, with the General, Security, Details tabs.. Windows Photo Viewer (I know it's not WPF) has this on it's context menu so I was hoping it to be a built in dialog somewhere in the win32 dlls.. If it's really not possible, then there's no choice. Thanks anyways.