# Specific Properties Tab using ShellExecute Properties Verb

Tags: c++, windows, shellexecute

Is there any way to open to a specific tab in properties using ShellExecute's Properties Verb?

Is there any way to do it at all? (Doesn't have to be ShellExecute, but can't find much that will display a file's "properties window")

(Mimicking the behavior of Right-clicking a file, selecting properties, and clicking on the Details tab)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one invoke the Windows Permissions dialog programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035464/how-does-one-invoke-the-windows-permissions-dialog-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. The following answers written in [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) were very helpful:

- [How do I display a file's Properties dialog from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1936957/4173303)
- [How does one invoke the Windows Permissions dialog programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28246897/4173303)

Here is some code:

```
// initalize COM
HRESULT  coInitRes = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);

SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {}; // initialize empty structure
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = "properties";
ShExecInfo.lpFile = "C:\\Users";
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = "Security";
// ShExecInfo.lpParameters = "Tools"; // if you want to open another tab
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
boolean result = ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
if (!result) {
    int res = GetLastError(); // this retrieves the error code
    // int res = (int) ShExecInfo.hInstApp; // this retrieves another error code
                            // on success, this value is 32
}

// close COM
if (coInitRes == S_OK || coInitRes == S_FALSE) { // do not call when result is RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

I'm not sure if you really have to call `CoInitializeEx` and `CoUninitialize`, but [the docs of ShellExecuteEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) state that it is good practice.

This example opens the *Security* tab of the *properties* dialog. You can change the value of `ShExecInfo.lpParameters` to specify another tab, for example `Tools`.

Note that if your application uses Unicode, you have to prepend an `L` to the string, for example:

```
ShExecInfo.lpFile = L"C:\\Users";
```