# Missing data in Windows file properties dialog when opened by ShellExecuteEx

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-properties, shellexecuteex

I want to show the Windows file properties dialog for a file from my C++ code (on Windows 7, using VS 2012). I found the following code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33472984/2675154) (which also contains a full MCVE). I also tried calling `CoInitializeEx()` first, as mentioned in the [documentation of `ShellExecuteEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
// Whether I initialize COM or not doesn't seem to make a difference.
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);

SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {0};

info.cbSize = sizeof info;
info.lpFile = L"D:\\Test.txt";
info.nShow  = SW_SHOW;
info.fMask  = SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST;
info.lpVerb = L"properties";

ShellExecuteEx(&info);
```

This code works, i.e. the properties dialog is shown and `ShellExecuteEx()` returns `TRUE`. However, in the *Details* tab, the size property is wrong and the date properties are missing:

[image: Properties window opened via my program]

The rest of the properties in the *Details* tab (e.g. the file attributes) are correct. Strangely, the size and date properties are shown correctly in the *General* tab (left-most tab).

If I open the properties window via the Windows Explorer (file → right-click → Properties), then all properties in the *Details* tab are shown correctly:

[image: Properties window opened via Windows Explorer]

I tried it with several files and file types (e.g. txt, rtf, pdf) on different drives and on three different PCs (1x German 64-bit Windows 7, 1x English 64-bit Windows 7, 1x English 32-bit Windows 7). I always get the same result, even if I run my program as administrator. On (64-bit) Windows 8.1 the code is working for me, though.

My original program in which I discovered the problem is an MFC application, but I see the same problem if I put the above code into a console application.

What do I have to do to show the correct values in the *Details* tab on Windows 7? Is it even possible?

Comment: For full details, all three Windows was german version? Upvote from me for interesting question.

Comment: Funny. FWIW I can reproduce this on a German Windows 7 (with English UI Language) using a simple test like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32503655/21567).

Comment: A wild guess - and I currently don't have the resources to test it out - but maybe Explorer uses the `IShellItem` or `IShellItem2` (or related interfaces) directly, rather than `ShellExecuteEx`. Maybe they work as expected.

Comment: Just a side note: `ShellExecuteEx` docs say that you should call `CoInitializeEx`. (I tried so, but it did not help with your problem.)

Comment: I think that problem is with formating digits using german locale. But currently I dont have English Win7 to test.

Comment: @WernerHenze I tried that with my test (see comment above), doesn't help either.

Comment: @WernerHenze: Thanks for the hint! I can confirm, that calling `CoInitializeEx()` doesn't make a difference. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @user2120666: I was able to reproduce the problem on two English installations of Windows 7. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, I wish upvote this question again.

Comment: @Christian.K: I took a look at `IShellItem(2)`, but I fail to see how I can use it to show the file properties dialog. I understood that you are busy, but in case you could drop me a function name (or whatever) in a comment, I'd be happy.

Comment: I didn't mean `IShellItem` in particular, but merely as a "placeholder" for something from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774328(v=vs.85).aspx) (I know it is a lot sorry). I will see if I can find out some more, until then, I can confirm that it is working on a German Windows 10 tough.

Comment: @Christian.K: No problem. Thanks for the list. I will try to dig through it.

Comment: Is the calling program using administrator access rights?

Comment: There is a lot more to that CoInitializeEx() call than meets the eye.  You are making a *promise*.  Breaking the promise causes deadlock.  The kind of app you created makes a big difference.  If this is a console mode app then you need to document that.

Comment: @HansPassant: My original program is an MFC application. But I see the same problem in my test program with is a console application.

Comment: @Codor: I had already tried running my program with administrator rights (it's mentioned at the end of my question). This doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Did you try specifying the file path by IDList? The documentation seems to be contradictory for that, it says _Use either lpFile to identify the item by its file system path or lpIDList to identify the item by its PIDL._ **but** _Note  SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST overrides and implies SEE_MASK_IDLIST_

Comment: @zett42: I only tried the code as shown in the question, so I didn't try to use the `lpIDList` member, yet. But you are right, the documentation reads a bit strange. I think I have to give it a try...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Raymond Chen suggested, replacing the path with a [PIDL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144089(v=vs.85).aspx) (`SHELLEXECUTEINFO::lpIDList`) makes the properties dialog correctly show the size and date fields under Windows 7 when invoked through `ShellExecuteEx()`.

It seems that the Windows 7 implementation of `ShellExecuteEx()` is buggy since  newer versions of the OS do not have an issue with `SHELLEXCUTEINFO::lpFile`.

There is another solution possible that involves creating an instance of [`IContextMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776095(v=vs.85).aspx) and calling the `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand()` method. I guess this is what `ShellExecuteEx()` does under the hood. Scroll down to **Solution 2** for example code.

## Solution 1 - using a PIDL with ShellExecuteEx

```
#include <atlcom.h>   // CComHeapPtr
#include <shlobj.h>   // SHParseDisplayName()
#include <shellapi.h> // ShellExecuteEx()

// CComHeapPtr is a smart pointer that automatically calls CoTaskMemFree() when
// the current scope ends.
CComHeapPtr<ITEMIDLIST> pidl;
SFGAOF sfgao = 0;

// Convert the path into a PIDL.
HRESULT hr = ::SHParseDisplayName( L"D:\\Test.txt", nullptr, &pidl, 0, &sfgao );
if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
{
    // Show the properties dialog of the file.

    SHELLEXECUTEINFO info{ sizeof(info) };
    info.hwnd = GetSafeHwnd();
    info.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    info.fMask = SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST;
    info.lpIDList = pidl;
    info.lpVerb = L"properties";

    if( ! ::ShellExecuteEx( &info ) )
    {
        // Make sure you don't put ANY code before the call to ::GetLastError() 
        // otherwise the last error value might be invalidated!
        DWORD err = ::GetLastError();

        // TODO: Do your error handling here.
    }
}
else
{
    // TODO: Do your error handling here
}
```

This code works for me under both Win 7 and Win 10 (other versions not tested) when called from a button click handler of a simple dialog-based MFC application.

It also works for console applications if you set `info.hwnd` to `NULL` (simply remove the line `info.hwnd = GetSafeHwnd();` from the example code as it is already initialized with 0). In the [SHELLEXECUTEINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784(v=vs.85).aspx) reference it is stated that the `hwnd` member is optional.

Don't forget the mandatory call to `CoInitialize()` or `CoInitializeEx()` at the startup of your application and `CoUninitialize()` at shutdown to properly initialize and deinitialize COM.

**Notes:**

[`CComHeapPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomheapptr-class) is a smart pointer included in ATL that automatically calls [`CoTaskMemFree()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680722(v=vs.85).aspx) when the scope ends. It's an ownership-transferring pointer with semantics similar to the deprecated [`std::auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr). That is, when you assign a `CComHeapPtr` object to another one, or use the constructor that has a `CComHeapPtr` parameter, the original object will become a NULL pointer.

```
CComHeapPtr<ITEMIDLIST> pidl2( pidl1 );  // pidl1 allocated somewhere before
// Now pidl1 can't be used anymore to access the ITEMIDLIST object.
// It has transferred ownership to pidl2!
```

I'm still using it because it is ready to use out-of-the-box and plays well together with the COM APIs.

---

## Solution 2 - using IContextMenu

The following code requires Windows Vista or newer as I'm using the "modern" [`IShellItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

I wrapped the code into a function `ShowPropertiesDialog()` that takes a window handle and a filesystem path. If any error occurs, the function throws a [`std::system_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) exception.

```
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <string>
#include <system_error>

/// Show the shell properties dialog for the given filesystem object.
/// \exception Throws std::system_error in case of any error.

void ShowPropertiesDialog( HWND hwnd, const std::wstring& path )
{
    using std::system_error;
    using std::system_category;

    if( path.empty() )
        throw system_error( std::make_error_code( std::errc::invalid_argument ), 
                            "Invalid empty path" );

    // SHCreateItemFromParsingName() returns only a generic error (E_FAIL) if 
    // the path is incorrect. We can do better:
    if( ::GetFileAttributesW( path.c_str() ) == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES )
    {
        // Make sure you don't put ANY code before the call to ::GetLastError() 
        // otherwise the last error value might be invalidated!
        DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
        throw system_error( static_cast<int>( err ), system_category(), "Invalid path" );
    }

    // Create an IShellItem from the path.
    // IShellItem basically is a wrapper for an IShellFolder and a child PIDL, simplifying many tasks.
    CComPtr<IShellItem> pItem;
    HRESULT hr = ::SHCreateItemFromParsingName( path.c_str(), nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS( &pItem ) );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        throw system_error( hr, system_category(), "Could not get IShellItem object" );

    // Bind to the IContextMenu of the item.
    CComPtr<IContextMenu> pContextMenu;
    hr = pItem->BindToHandler( nullptr, BHID_SFUIObject, IID_PPV_ARGS( &pContextMenu ) );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        throw system_error( hr, system_category(), "Could not get IContextMenu object" );

    // Finally invoke the "properties" verb of the context menu.
    CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO cmd{ sizeof(cmd) };
    cmd.lpVerb = "properties";
    cmd.hwnd = hwnd;
    cmd.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;

    hr = pContextMenu->InvokeCommand( &cmd );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        throw system_error( hr, system_category(), 
            "Could not invoke the \"properties\" verb from the context menu" );
}
```

In the following I show an example of how to use `ShowPropertiesDialog()` from a button handler of a CDialog-derived class. Actually `ShowPropertiesDialog()` is independent from MFC, as it just needs a window handle, but OP mentioned that he wants to use the code in an MFC app.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <codecvt>

// Convert a multi-byte (ANSI) string returned from std::system_error::what()
// to Unicode (UTF-16).
std::wstring MultiByteToWString( const std::string& s )
{
    std::wstring_convert< std::codecvt< wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t >> conv;
    try { return conv.from_bytes( s ); }
    catch( std::range_error& ) { return {}; }
}

// A button click handler.
void CMyDialog::OnPropertiesButtonClicked()
{
    std::wstring path( L"c:\\temp\\test.txt" );

    // The code also works for the following paths:
    //std::wstring path( L"c:\\temp" );
    //std::wstring path( L"C:\\" );
    //std::wstring path( L"\\\\127.0.0.1\\share" );
    //std::wstring path( L"\\\\127.0.0.1\\share\\test.txt" );

    try
    {
        ShowPropertiesDialog( GetSafeHwnd(), path );
    }
    catch( std::system_error& e )
    {
        std::wostringstream msg;
        msg << L"Could not open the properties dialog for:\n" << path << L"\n\n"
            << MultiByteToWString( e.what() ) << L"\n"
            << L"Error code: " << e.code();
        AfxMessageBox( msg.str().c_str(), MB_ICONERROR );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure. It worked for me on Win 7 x64 aswell as Win 10 x64. I could provide at least rudimentary error handling / cleanup, but currently I don't have much time either, so I hope the sample code is OK for you as is.

Comment: I think you don't have to go this far. I think you can just get the pidl and set it in the SHELLEXECUTEINFO.lpIDList. Passing an explicit IDList means that the shell will use it directly instead of trying to create a simple one.

Comment: @zett42: Do you know if your code also works in a console application? I put it into a test console application, but the properties dialog doesn't show up for me. However, all functions return S_OK and all returned pointers seem to be valid handles. For the `eaten` values 0 is returned, though. For `hwnd` I tried `NULL` and the return value of `FindWindow()` on the console window title. Am I missing something here? Sorry for being stupid! I'll try it in my MFC program and the `lpIDList` idea later.

Comment: @honk Maybe it needs a window actually belonging to your process. You don't own the console window, [it belongs to csrss.exe](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071231-00/?p=23983). Is your real application where you need this code a console or did you just use this for quick testing?

Comment: @zett42: Ok, this might explain it. I just used a console application for quick testing. I don't have access to my original program (MFC application) right now. I'll try your code later in that application.

Comment: Thanks @Raymond, using a PIDL makes this work. I somehow got more attracted by the complex solution using `IContextMenu` instead of following my own initial suggestion.

Comment: @honk Great! I will add back my first solution if I find some time in the evening.

Comment: @Raymond Is it actually correct to call `CoTaskMemFree()` to deallocate the PIDL returned by `SHParseDisplayName()` as the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762236(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't say anything about that? I just took that from this [general documentation about PIDLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144089(v=vs.85).aspx) -> "allocating PIDLs".

Comment: @zett42 CoTaskMemFree is the standard way of freeing memory passed between COM components.

Comment: @honk I added my first solution back, but in a "modernized" form that requires less boilerplate code and also works with root pathes like "C:\". BTW, there is much to learn from [Raymonds blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) about the modernized shell API. Just search for `IShellItem`. Good stuff.

Comment: Thank you for taking the effort! Excellent answer! It teaches me a lot. However, the Windows Shell is still a closed book for me. I will take a look at Raymond's blog. Just two questions: Why does the first solution use `CComHeapPtr` and the second one `CComPtr`? Does the latter work in the same way as the former?

Comment: `CComHeapPtr` is for raw memory allocated by COM components (CoTaskMemAlloc/CoTaskMemFree), `CComPtr` is for class objects that are reference-counted (AddRef/Release). As a rule of thumb: everything that is returned as a pointer to a class with a big "I" prefix, should be managed via `CComPtr`. The `CComPtr` automatically calls the `Release()` method when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: @honk _Do you know if your code also works in a console application_ ... [Normally, the ShellExecuteEx function assumes that there will be a message pump running after it returns](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041126-00/?p=37193) ... but the suggestion of adding `SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT` doesn't work on my Win10 machine. Adding a `MessageBox()` call after `ShellExecuteEx()` to run a message loop works though.

Comment: @zett42: Thank you very much for the follow-up. This is interesting to know. Fortunately, your first solution seem to work perfectly in my MFC application on all Windows versions.